# Can JMeter JDBC pre-processor accept multiple Insert/delete/update queries?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

Can JMeter JDBC pre-processor accept multiple Insert/delete/update  queries?

I have added two queries:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter can do whatever underlying [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) can do, for example for [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) you can specify [`allowMultiQueries` JDBC URL parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) and you will be able to separate statements by semicolon.

Looking into `oracle` pool variable name my expectation is that you're trying to test an Oracle database and its JDBC driver doesn't support this feature.

The options are in:

1. Create a [stored procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_programs.htm) which will delete multiple records
2. Parameterize existing JDBC PreProcessor using i.e. [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile), in this case you will not have to copy and paste the preprocessors
3. Use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) instead of the JDBC PreProcessor and implement your records deletion logic there, take a look at [Statement.addBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String)) function, you can combine multiple queries into one statement with it. Check out [Using Statement Objects for Batch Updates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#batch_updates) chapter of the [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit multiple queries as is, because you **can't use `;`** in JDBC request

But you can use other techniques to insert/delete multiple records, for example using `IN`

```
delete from CPAY where bnf_nic_name in ('BillerBBJ929' ,'BillerOFV864')
```

Comment: i will have multiple delete query from different table not in same table, in that case how we can handle it. @user7294900

Comment: @AvnishRathore Create JDBC request per table, I don't think there's a workaround it